# Getting form field value separately in AJAX while using the "serialize" method

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am using AJAX to process my form data. I have to write multiple functions for multiple form. But I was thinking if I could use a single ajax function for multiple forms from different pages. For example, currently I am using it like this:

```
// Update Password
$('#updPass').click(function() {
  var form = document.updPass;
  var dataString = $(form).serialize();
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'processes/settings.php',
    data: dataString,
    cache: true,
    beforeSend: function(){
      $('.message').hide();
      $("#updPass").val('Please wait...');
    },
    success: function(html){
      $("#updPass").val('Save');
      $('.message').html(html).fadeIn();
    }
  });
  return false;
});

// Add New Room
$('#addRoom').click(function() {
  var form = document.addRoom;
  var dataString = $(form).serialize();
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'processes/rooms.php',
    data: dataString,
    cache: true,
    beforeSend: function(){
      $('.message').hide();
      $("#addRoom").val('Please wait...');
    },
    success: function(html){
      $("#addRoom").val('Save');
      $('.message').html(html).fadeIn();
    }
  });
  return false;
});
```

But I want to use it like this:

```
// Perform action
$('#addNew').click(function() {
  var form = document.addNew;
  var dataString = $(form).serialize();
  var formFieldToIdentify = "Take input from 1 hidden form field and store here";
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    if(formFieldToIdentify == 'password'){
      url: 'processes/settings.php',
    }else{
      url: 'processes/rooms.php',
    }
    data: dataString,
    cache: true,
    beforeSend: function(){
      $('.message').hide();
      $("#addNew").val('Please wait...');
    },
    success: function(html){
      $("#addNew").val('Save');
      $('.message').html(html).fadeIn();
    }
  });
  return false;
});
```

How to obtain that `formFieldToIdentify` variable from the form here? If I am able to get it I can use it easily. If I collected the form values separately the job would have been done. But here, I am using the serialize method and hence unable to separately get this form field value.

Comment: Use `addNew` and other ids of the buttons that you click.

Comment: an hidden form field with appropriate value for each kind of form ?

Comment: Make a variable `form_IDs` and store statically the ID's of the form you're using in it. then make an `event listener` for all submit form buttons. and **when any button clicks then find its form ID attribute value.** So make a switch statement which will  recieve the form ID after clicking the button and use switch cases for each and every form ID'S. That's it.

Comment: and Inside `switch-cases` you just need to give the values of **url**, **method** like `url='./process/form1.process.php'`, `method='post'`. and use these variables in your AJAX.

Answer (score 0):

As an option you can create an object where you store your urls and then select required url by key:

```
var urls = {
    addNew: 'processes/rooms.php',
    someUrl: 'processes/file1.php',
    //...
};

$('#addNew').click(function() {
  var form = document.addNew;
  var dataString = $(form).serialize();
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: urls.addNew,
    data: dataString,
    cache: true,
    beforeSend: function(){
      $('.message').hide();
      $("#addNew").val('Please wait...');
    },
    success: function(html){
      $("#addNew").val('Save');
      $('.message').html(html).fadeIn();
    }
  });
  return false;
});
```

Another option: you can define urls in `form`'s `action` attribute:

```
<form action="/file.php" method="POST">
```

In your script:

```
$('#addNew').click(function() {
  var form = document.addNew;
  var dataString = $(form).serialize();
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: $(form).attr("action"),
    data: dataString,
    cache: true,
    beforeSend: function(){
      $('.message').hide();
      $("#addNew").val('Please wait...');
    },
    success: function(html){
      $("#addNew").val('Save');
      $('.message').html(html).fadeIn();
    }
  });
  return false;
});
```

Comment: It looks like that you have to initialize `$('#someID').click` for each form in every pages. This is not dynamic method.

Comment: @u_mulder That's not what I want. According to your answer I will have to write whole ajax function separately and user `url: urls.someUrl` next time and so on. If I had to do this then writing the urls straight away without storing them in the variables is one and the same thing. What I wanted was to avoid writing whole ajax function again and again for similar form submissions and just use an if else to send form data to required processing files using 1 single ajax function.

Comment: @GoldenFriendshipSite I also gave you an idea for how can you accomplish this (see my comments below your question)

Comment: @AbhishekKamal what you wrote is confusing. If you could show it as an answer just like u_mulder here did that it would be clear for me.

Comment: @GoldenFriendshipSite updated my answer with another option.

Answer (score 0):

Previus answer is good too, I just wanted to clear that you cant send data to multiple urls with one function.

For sending data to multiple pages you need to created nested functions in ajax, which will start all functions with same button clicked.

But you can get values from multiple forms in same page or in different pages without changing function each time like following example.

```
$('#updPass').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var url = $(this).attr('action'); //auto detect action url
    var results = [];
    $('form').each(function(){
        results.push($(this).serialize());
        // serializeArray(); is much more suitable
        //results.push($(this).serializeArray());
    });
    $.ajax({
        'url': url,
        'type': 'POST', // type not method
        'data': {data: JSON.stringify(results)},
        'dataType': 'html',
        'success': function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
});
```

Note you need to specify url in form action

Server side in php part,

```
var_dump(json_decode($_POST));
var_dump($_POST);
```

Answer (score 0):

So you told me that you didn't get my idea that I was told you.
So this is the brief answer of my idea.
Suppose you have three forms in different pages or in a **same page** like this -

```
<form id='registration_form'>
    form fields like input, radio buttons, checkboxes, textareas etc
    <input type='submit' class='form_btn'>
</form>

//***************************
<form id='login_form'>
    form fields like input, radio buttons, checkboxes, textareas etc
    <input type='submit' class='form_btn'>
</form>
//***************************
<form id='update_form'>
    add form fields like input, radio buttons, checkboxes, textareas etc
    <input type='submit' class='form_btn'>
</form>
//****************************
```

Each form has unique id attribute and a common class for button.

```
<script>
    // create variables
    let process_url, method, form, dataString;
    // for submit button.
    let form_btn = document.getElementsByClassName('form_btn');

    // AJAX code to process the form data.
    function your_ajax_function(){
       $.ajax({
    type: method,
    url: process_url,
    data: dataString,
    cache: true,
    beforeSend: function(){
      // fetch those ID's and classes in function set_dynamic_variables()
      // and then use here.
    },
    success: function(html){
      // fetch those ID's and classes in function set_dynamic_variables()
      // and then use here.
    }
  });

    }

    function set_dynamic_variables(e){
        form = //write your own code to fetch the form-ID in which e is present.

        switch (form) {

            case 'registration_form':
                process_url = './process/registration_form.process.php';
                method = 'POST';
                dataString = $('#' + form).serialize();    
                break;

            case 'login_form':
                process_url = './process/login_form.process.php';
                method = 'POST';
                dataString = $('#' + form).serialize();               
                break;

            case 'update_form':
                process_url = './process/update_form.process.php';
                method = 'POST';
                dataString = $('#' + form).serialize();                
                break;

                default:
                // statements_def
                break;
        } // switch()
        } // if

// adding the event-listener for all the submit button of forms
for(let i=0; i< submit_btn.length; i++){
    submit_btn[i].addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        set_dynamic_variables(e);
        your_ajax_function();
    }, false);


</script>
```

***@Golden Friendship Site*** So, This is what I told you in discussion.
and my code will be able to work correctly even if you put all form in a same page.