# PHP array with MySQL data

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json

I have to send the list of all the users through JSON to javascript.
The problem is that I don't know the function to store all the data in one variables.

This is my code:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM ___ WHERE __ = ___ ";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

while( /* from here I don't know which function should be inserted */)


$json = json_encode('something');

echo $json;
```

Comment: see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/60137289/12232340

Comment: I am just gonna link this here, because I smell problems: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php

Comment: What about reading the documentation or a tutorial? Read [ask], this was asked 1000000 times before!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your code is vulnerable to SQL injection. I need to point it out that if you have variable input (which I assume you do in WHERE clause) you need to bind the input via prepared statements.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM yourTable WHERE someColumn = ? ";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param('s', $someVariable);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();

// Now fetch it into an array
$arrayOfRows = $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

// echo out JSON
echo json_encode($arrayOfRows);
```

There is no need for any loop, especially not `while` loop. Just fetch all the records into a multidimensional array.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM ___ WHERE __ = ___ ";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

$data_array = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result) ){
   $data_array[] = $row;
}

$json = json_encode($data_array);

echo $json;
```

Comment: Could you please explain why? This is definitely not the recommended way of fetching results via mysqli, so you need to explain why you suggested this.

Comment: I only focused on `send the list of all the users through JSON to javascript`. I thought that he knows how to prevent injections.